# Unable to filter a queryset by using year and month

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My model is:

```
class Procedure(models.Model):
    procid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    timestr = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    template = models.ForeignKey(ProcedureTemplate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(doctor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

I am trying to filter a queryset by year and month on a model property.

If I filter by year:

```
procedures = Procedure.objects.filter(clinic = clinicobj, timestr__year=2020)
for proc in procedures:
    print(f'{proc.pk} {proc.timestr}')
```

I get:

```
66 2020-01-08 12:38:37.237585+00:00
67 2020-01-11 15:40:00.344492+00:00
68 2020-01-12 04:50:56.190794+00:00
69 2020-01-26 05:58:36.962205+00:00
70 2020-01-29 09:51:59.038017+00:00
71 2020-02-01 14:24:18.921779+00:00
72 2020-02-09 06:20:30.993496+00:00
73 2020-02-15 10:23:09.068201+00:00
74 2020-02-15 14:04:29.368066+00:00
75 2020-02-16 06:25:09.702327+00:00
76 2020-02-19 14:05:19.369457+00:00
77 2020-02-20 11:13:35.934392+00:00
```

However when I try to narrow it down by adding the month, I am getting no results. What's wrong here?

```
Procedure.objects.filter(clinic = clinicobj, timestr__year=2020, timestr__month=2)

<QuerySet []>

Procedure.objects.filter(clinic = clinicobj, timestr__year=2020).filter(clinic = clinicobj, timestr__month=2)

<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Could you share your model?

Comment: @kamilyrb I have shared it.

Comment: I think the month needs a leading zero.  Try `timestr__month='02'`

Comment: Could you add this line to your settings.py and try again? USE_TZ = False

Comment: I can test. But I do need time zone for my app. Adding a leading zero didnt help.

Comment: Yes I want to only you are test it, if it works, I will suggest a solution

Comment: @kamilyrb Changing it to False did fix it. Leading zeros were not required.

Comment: Good, which db are you using?Mysql,sqlite.. etc

Comment: @kamilyrb mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on documentation

> "When USE_TZ is True, datetime fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering. This requires time zone definitions in the database."

So if you use mysql, you can install pytz and load the time zone tables with [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).

Also you can follow [databases document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#mysql-time-zone-definitions) in django.I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using `Extract*` and would also suggest checking the timezone used to save the datetime values.

> With USE_TZ = True. Convert the datetime using (timezone.make_aware(value))

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear


procedures = (
    Procedure.objects
    .annotate(
        year=ExtractYear('timestr'), 
        month=ExtractMonth('timestr'),
    )
    .filter(
        clinic=clinicobj, 
        year=2020, 
        month=2,
    )
)
for proc in procedures:
    print(f'{proc.pk} {proc.timestr}')
```

Result

```
71 2020-02-01 14:24:18.921779+00:00
72 2020-02-09 06:20:30.993496+00:00
73 2020-02-15 10:23:09.068201+00:00
74 2020-02-15 14:04:29.368066+00:00
75 2020-02-16 06:25:09.702327+00:00
76 2020-02-19 14:05:19.369457+00:00
77 2020-02-20 11:13:35.934392+00:00
```