# Django: Count objects by month

Tags: django

I studied the Django docu and tried many examples but it still doesn't work, though it should be very easy, actually.

This is my model:

```
class Dummy(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

I have some sample objects which I am able to list via the shell like that:

```
% python manage.py shell
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from conv.models import Dummy
>>> dummy = Dummy.objects.order_by('timestamp')
>>> for d in dummy:
...     print(d.id, d.timestamp)

6 2019-05-01 07:00:06+00:00
4 2020-04-01 22:00:00+00:00
5 2020-04-15 04:00:00+00:00
1 2020-05-17 09:42:00+00:00
2 2020-05-18 09:42:15+00:00
3 2020-05-19 09:42:21+00:00
>>>
```

Now I want to count the objects by year / month. Filtering by year only works:

```
>>> Dummy.objects.filter(timestamp__year='2020').count()
5
```

But filtering by month doesn't work:

```
>>> Dummy.objects.filter(timestamp__month='5').count()
0
```

Actually the result should be 4. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some trouble with the MySQL-DB I was using very similar to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60361363/13520223). When I switched back to SQLite I got the correct result:

```
>>> Dummy.objects.filter(timestamp__month='5').count()
4
```

Now I also can combine filtering for year and month like that:

```
>>> Dummy.objects.filter(timestamp__year='2020', timestamp__month='5').count()
3
```

Thanks to the [generous help of Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61888568/13520223) I see things clearer now and learned a lot about TruncMonth and ExtractMonth which seems to be very useful tools too.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a [**`TruncMonth`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth) to obtain a queryset of dictionaries where `month` is a `datetime` object that always specifies the first of the month, and `count` will contain the number of items for that given month:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

Dummy.objects.values(
    month=TruncMonth('timestamp')
).annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('month')
```

Or for a given month, you can use [**`ExtractMonth`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractMonth):

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

Dummy.objects.values(
    month=ExtractMonth('timestamp'),
    year=ExtractMonth('timestamp')
).filter(
    year=2020,
    month=5
).count()
```

Comment: OK, the dictionaries looks like this:

`{'month': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)}`

You say: "… count will contain the number of items for that given month", but there is no "count" yet, so I still have to count the items per month, right?

Comment: @RalfZosel: sorry, there was a typo in the answer that has hidden the `count=...` part, see edit.

Comment: Now `count` is in the dictionaries which is fine, but actually my intention was to get it "standalone". By the way: My filtering example I mentioned in my question `Dummy.objects.filter(timestamp__month='5').count()` do deliver 4 – I have no idea what I did wrong earlier. (I will correct this in the question, OK?) Of course the combination of year and month wich TruncMonth delivers is much better. The question is now: How can I filter for that? Something like `Dummy.objects.values(month=TruncMonth('timestamp')).filter(month='2020-05-01 00:00').count()` delivers 0 (instead of 3).

Comment: @RalfZosel: what if you use `ExtractMonth`? See edit.

Comment: Works great and can be combined with filtering by year: `Dummy.objects.values(year=ExtractYear('timestamp'), month=ExtractMonth('timestamp')).filter(year=2020, month=5).count()` delivers 3 which is fine. Well, actually that's very similar to my solution which I first had in mind: `Dummy.objects.filter(timestamp__year='2020', timestamp__month='5').count()`. However, I have learned a lot by that, thank you very much for your help! My original problem had obviously something to do with mysql and tz as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60361363/13520223 (I switched to SQLite meanwhile).

Comment: @J-a-n-u-s: this lets the boldface dissapear,. and furthermore the backslahes are not necessary, it is not a "hanging" expression, the brackets ensure that it remains the same expression.