# Django: Fill the gaps in a view which is grouped by month

Tags: django, django-views

My problem seems to be quite standard and I found many solutions, but none which works for a Django view.

I have timestamped items ("conversions") and I want to show the number of items per month. My view deliver this:

```
2020-05     3
2020-03     2
```

What I need is this:

```
2020-05     3
2020-04     0
2020-03     2
```

models.py:

```
class Conversion(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py (thanks to [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61888568/13520223)):

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

def conversions_monthly(request):

    conv = Conversion.objects.values(month=TruncMonth(
        'timestamp')).annotate(count=Count('pk')).order_by('-month')
    context = {'conversion': conv}
    return render(request, 'dummy/conversions_monthly.html', context)
```

Template conversions_monthly.html:

```
{% extends "dummy/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table>
    {% for c in conversion %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ c.month |date:"Y-m" }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ c.count }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Data:

```
[
{
   "model": "dummy.conversion",
   "pk": 1,
   "fields": {
      "project": 1,
      "timestamp": "2020-03-10T05:00:00Z"
   }
},
{
   "model": "dummy.conversion",
   "pk": 2,
   "fields": {
      "project": 1,
      "timestamp": "2020-03-12T17:00:00Z"
   }
},
{
   "model": "dummy.conversion",
   "pk": 3,
   "fields": {
      "project": 1,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-19T12:00:00Z"
   }
},
{
   "model": "dummy.conversion",
   "pk": 4,
   "fields": {
      "project": 2,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-20T16:10:03Z"
   }
},
{
   "model": "dummy.conversion",
   "pk": 5,
   "fields": {
      "project": 1,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-20T16:30:00Z"
   }
}
]
```

I guess, I have to "aggregate" somehow the min and max date and need something like:

```
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

result = []

max = date(2020, 5, 20)
min = date(2020, 3, 1)

current = min

while current <= max:
    result.append(current)
    current += relativedelta(months=1)
```

which delivers `[datetime.date(2020, 3, 1), datetime.date(2020, 4, 1), datetime.date(2020, 5, 1)]`

I have no idea how to get these pieces together – or is there a completely different approach for that in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inspired by Nader Alexan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61955982/13520223) I found the following solution which delivers the desired result. _min and _max are no longer fix, but calculated now.

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
from django.db.models import Max, Min

def conversions_monthly(request):

    conversions = Conversion.objects.values(month=TruncMonth('timestamp')).annotate(
        count=Count('pk'))

    result = []

    _min = Conversion.objects.aggregate(Min('timestamp'))[
        'timestamp__min'].date().replace(day=1)
    _max = Conversion.objects.aggregate(Max('timestamp'))[
        'timestamp__max'].date().replace(day=1)

    current = _max.replace(day=1)

    while current >= _min:

        c = conversions.filter(month__year=current.year).filter(
            month__month=current.month)

        if c:
            result.append({"date": current, "count": c[0]['count']})
        else:
            result.append({"date": current, "count": 0})
        current -= relativedelta(months=1)

    context = {'conversion': result}
    return render(request, 'dummy/conversions_monthly.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path already, here is your code stitched together

```py
# views.py

def index(request):
    result = []
    # `min` and `max` are keywords in python, so it is bad practice to use them as variable names
    _max = datetime.date(2020, 5, 20)
    _min = datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)
    current = _min
    while current <= _max:
        result.append({"date": current, "count": 0})
        current += relativedelta(months=1)


    conversions = Conversion.objects.values(month=TruncMonth(
        'timestamp')).annotate(count=Count('pk')).order_by('-month')

    # the conditions for checking `i` being smaller than `length` protect you in case there are no conversions in your range
    i = 0
    length = len(result)
    for conversion in conversions:
        while i < length and \
            not (
                result[i]["date"].year == conversion["month"].year and 
                result[i]["date"].month == conversion["month"].month
                ):
            i += 1
        if i < length:
            result[i]["count"] = conversion["count"]

    context = {'conversion': result}
    return render(request, 'dummy/conversions_monthly.html', context)
```

template

```html
{% extends "dummy/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table>
    {% for c in conversion %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ c.date |date:"Y-m" }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ c.count }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code. It delivers nothing in the month-column and 0, 0, 3 in the count-column, unfortunately. Would'n it be easier to simply look in the first while-loop if there exist an appropriate conversion und to adopt their count – otherwise 0?

Comment: Did you update your template? I changed the `c.month` to `c.date`

Comment: You are right, that was my mistake. Meanwhile I found a slightly easier solution.

Comment: if my code helped you, it would be nice to upvote it.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your hint. Sorry, but I am quite new here and I am still learning how all this works. Despite your code does not give the correct result (0, 0, 3 instead of 3, 0, 2 in the count-column), it inspired me to find a solution which works and therefore I am very happy and thank you very much for your help.